# C# During Monitor.Wait, Did the thread use CPU resource?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu, monitor

During the ThreadTest is waited by Monitor.Wait, Did the ThreadTest use CPU resource?

Here is my code:

```
void ThreadTest()  
{  
    lock (ObjectA)  
    {  
       ...  

       lock (ObjectB)   
       {  
           while (Condition)  
           {  
                Monitor.Wait(ObjectB);  
           }  
       }  

       ...  

    }   
}  


void Resume()  
{  
     lock (ObjectB)  
     {  
          Condition = true;  
          Monitor.Pulse(ObjectB);  
     }  
}
```

I will like to know does the while(Condition) call Monitor.Wait continuously?

Comment: Are the methods ThreadTest and Resume on different threads

Comment: @EmrahSüngü  Yes, Resume is on UI Thread. ThreadTest is work thread and is started by UI Thread

Comment: There are tools where you can easily check the CPU usage of your thread, e.g. Process Monitor

Comment: @DirkVollmar When I saw the Process Monitor, CPU usage changed little. So I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Monitor.Wait()` blocks execution until another thread calls `Pulse()`. It is designed to use as little as possible resources while waiting.